# Bind a key to accept the first suggested word function in Fish

Tags: shell, vi, fish

I use the vi keybinding mode in Fish.
Alt+Right works but I need to move my hand away from hjkl.

Is it possible to bind a key like Alt+l to accept the first suggest word?

Thank you.

Comment: For questions about interactive environment configuration (vs writing scripts), consider our sister site [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/); Stack Overflow is only for questions about *software development* and tools exclusive to that use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the binding is `nextd-or-forward-word`. So you could write:

```
bind \el nextd-or-forward-word
```

`\el` is probably alt-L on your system as well, but you can double check by running `fish-key_reader`.

Comment: For vi, it seems I need to add "-M insert"
That works! Thank you.